# Free Text search on Hyperledger Fabric CouchDB Data with Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

We use Hyperledger fabric backed by CouchDB to store records with a lot of text. We want to build a solution that allows free text search on these records using Elastic Search. The problem then is getting the fabric/CouchDB data into elastic search in real time. What's the best way to do it. I can think of three approaches:-

**1) Create a service** that listens to the CouchDB changes feed in *continuous mode*(Couch has great support for this) and pushes the changes to a message queue(Kafka). Another service can then read from Kafka and push to Elastic Search. I like this idea('change data capture') because we could then build off other read views from our Kafka log. **Cons of this approach**:

- Though we are using hyperledger fabric, we are programming to the underlying data store(CouchDB). **What happens if hyperledger moves to MongoDB after a year**(or decides to support it along with CouchDB and we want to move to MongoDB ) ? We will have to rewrite/change our Kafka connectors.
- **Maintain two states**: 1) The offset of the last document read from CouchDB changes feed and 2)The Kafka offset. We can use Zookeeper for this ?

**2) Have our client application**(the one that writes to fabric) publish an event to a Kafka every time it writes/updates to fabric. Another service could then read those events and write to Elastic. **The biggest con of this approach is:**

- We enter the realm of **dual writes**(1 to fabric, 1 to Kafka) and there's no good way of doing both atomically. This leaves us **susceptible to race conditions and partial failures**(write to fabric succeeds but write to kafka fails etc etc).

**3) I believe hyperlerdger fabric** peers provide something called 'event services' which publish events every time it writes to the ledger. However, **the docs for this one aren't great** and I can't find any examples. Could you elaborate on this if you have experience with it ? **My biggest problem with this approach is that hasn't been battle tested yet** and a lot of developer time will go into fixing things when they go wrong because of the lack of docs/blogs/examples etc.

Thank you so much in advance for the help.

Comment: As per my experience you should go with approach 1 as it follow a single stream of data flow and you can easily track failure.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended pattern is #3 - listen for block events and have the listener insert whatever data is desired into a queryable data store such as Elasticsearch. With the channel based event services, a listener client registers for events from a certain starting block onwards. If there is any disruption in service, the listener client can always resume from where it left off.

This pattern specifically, and usage of event services generally, is described in the [Node.js SDK event tutorial](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/tutorial-channel-events.html).